# Yii2 when urlManager is enabled i get 404 error

Tags: .htaccess, yii, yii2

i created a project in Yii2.
When i enable urlManager in configs i get 404 error.

```
'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',

        ],
    ],
```

in my htaccess i have

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

when i open url like this https://www.example.eu/yii/web/site/contact/
i get

> The requested URL /yii/web/site/contact/ was not found on this server.

/yii/ is folder on server where is my project

without urlManager all working fine.
Maybe i forgot about something?

Comment: Did you tried without trailing slash (`https://www.example.eu/yii/web/site/contact`)?

Comment: yes, it is not working too

Comment: Does `https://www.example.eu/yii/web/index.php/site/contact` work?

Comment: My mistake was in server configuration